# What does cm = plt.cm.RdBu mean?

Tags: python, matplotlib

After I run this code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cm = plt.cm.RdBu
cm_bright = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#0000FF'])
ax = plt.subplot()  

ax.set_title("Input data")
# Plot the training points
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cm_bright)
ax.set_xticks(())
ax.set_yticks(())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The code above show the image like this:
[image]

However, when I annotate the code `cm = plt.cm.RdBu` ,the result doesn't change.
So, the question is what is the usage for the code `cm = plt.cm.RdBu` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, the variable `cm` isn't used anywhere in the script, so you can comment it out without changing anything.

`cm = plt.cm.RdBu` denotes a colormap, just like the later defined `cm_bright = ListedColormap(..)`. So you might want to use it instead:

```
ax.scatter(..., cmap=cm)
```

For a complete list of colormap see the [matplotlib colormap reference](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).